# PredictionIO elasticsearch demo causting error

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, cluster-computing, predictionio

I ran "pio app new tapster" and cannot get past this error. My elasticsearch.yml file appears. My network is correctly set. But, don't know how to get based this.

```
[WARN] [transport] [Portal] node [#transport#-1][Jeremys-MacBook-Pro.local][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9300]] not part of the cluster Cluster [elasticsearch], ignoring...
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:278)
```

Comment: Did you start the elasticsearch? try `pio-start-all`. Also what happen what output you get for  `pio status`?